# Distributed TensorFlow 2.0 does not work when using more than 26 workers on a single machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a performance issue using distributed TF using CPU machine with `MultiWorkerStrategy` for more than 26 workers. I use Intel Xeon Gold 6150 2.7GHz 18 cores (16 cores enabled) 24.75MB L3 Cache (Max Turbo Freq. 3.7GHz, Min 3.4GHz), 180GB RAM (Six Channel), 4.8TB of Disk Space. However, it seems that it does not work as the following errors:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0502 21:43:31.821069 47528963346944 cross_device_ops.py:1106] Not all devices in tf.distribute.Strategy are visible to TensorFlow.
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0502 21:43:31.821974 47863205896704 cross_device_ops.py:1106] Not all devices in tf.distribute.Strategy are visible to TensorFlow.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

It works until 25 number of workers. Is it because of insufficient memory from the machine?